# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list....but it's not missing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code I'm having a problem with:

```
<script>
$( "li#1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 1</span>" ) );
        } function() {    
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);
$( "li#2" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 2</span>" ) );
        } function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);
</script>
```

There is no problem with li#2, even though li#1 has identical syntax but is getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in li#1. Where am I missing the parenthesis? NetBeans debugger tells me it's in the line } function() { which is identical for both.

Comment: Are you missing a comma between the two functions?

Comment: Where did you got this hover function syntax?

Comment: @palaѕн From jQuery documentation...

Comment: I suggest re-think the HTML structure with CSS skill instead. Do user behavior using CSS first, then JavaScript.

Comment: As @Justinas said, it was at https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing commas to separate the multiple functions in each of your `.hover()`'s

```
<script>
$( "li#1" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 1</span>" ) );
    }, // <-- comma added here
    function() {    
        $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);

$( "li#2" ).hover(
    function() {
        $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 2</span>" ) );
    }, // <-- comma added here
    function() {
        $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the missing commas in both `.hover()` statements. Try this:

```js
$( "li#1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 1</span>" ) );
        }, 
  function() {    
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);
$( "li#2" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 2</span>" ) );
        }, 
  function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="1">One: </li>
  <li id="2">Two: </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after first function definition for both `li#1` and `li#2`

```
$( "li#1" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>Answer 1</span>" ) );
  }, //notice comma before function
  function() {     
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: And the second hover function too!